# Design entity model to manage multiple bidirectionnal relations

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to find the best way to design relations between entities from my model. I'll try to explain it clearly.

Imagine the following Doctrine2 entities:

```
class ImageHistory
{
    /**
     * @var Image
     */
    protected $current;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    protected $old;
}

class Dog
{
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var ImageHistory
     */
    protected $imageHistory;
}

class Cat
{
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var ImageHistory
     */
    protected $imageHistory;
}
```

I would like to establish two one-to-many bidirectional Doctrine relations where `Cat` and `Dog` are the owning sides of the relations. Both `Cat` and `Dog` classes have this entity configuration:

```
manyToOne:
    imageHistory:
        targetEntity: ImageHistory
        joinColumn:
            name: image_history_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

How to represent the other side of te relation ?

```
oneToMany:
    owner:
        targetEntity: <What can I write here?>
        mappedBy: imageHistory
```

I imagine a solution where `Cat` and `Dog` inherite an `Animal` entity class, so I can move the ManyToOne relation into the `Animal` class and put `Animal` as targetEntity of the OneToMany relation. But the problem reappears if I have a new `SoundHistory` entity and: `Cat`, `Dog` and new `Car` and `Boat` classes must have a relation to it.

A can't just add `SoundHistory` as oneToMany relation to the `Animal` class because `Car` and `Boat` won't inherite from it. So I still can't fill the `targetEntity` of my OneToMany relation in the `ImageHistory` entity.

What is the best way to design the entity model in this case?

Comment: Could you explain the relationships in SQL?

Comment: Use interface? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649553/doctrine-orm-use-interface-as-relation-for-different-entities

Comment: Use some AbstractEntity? kinda MotherOfAllObjects/Entities

Comment: You can use @OneToMany Annotation. see at [enter link description here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

A [Many-To-One Relation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) is unidirectional, so you can't represent the other side.

Also, you should consider creating a super entity, if you really want to store the Dogs and Cats in the same table.

Comment: Actually, Many-To-One can be bidir (see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you need is use a separate join table to represent the relations between `Cat`, `Dog` and `ImageHistory`, `SoundHistory`. For this you can use one to many unidirectional mapping with join table. Doctrine docs found here, thanks to NaeiKinDus: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

The point is - image & sound histories are stored independently and the join table `cat_image_history` stores which `Cat` owns which `ImageHistory`. So Doctrine will get your cat's `id`, check the `cat_image_history` and get the correct `ImageHistory` by `image_history_id`. Same way you can add `SoundHistory` only for dogs or for both cats and dogs.

The mapping can look something like this:

```
Cat:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    imageHistory:
      targetEntity: ImageHistory
      joinTable:
        name: cat_image_history
        joinColumns:
          cat_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          image_history_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            unique: true
```